# orientationDidChangeNotification has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange'

Tags: swift, flutter

i am updated to flutter 2.10 and get this issue in ios MLKit in the class

> OrientationHandler

in this section of the handler code

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: orientationDidChange(_:))
```

i get this error :

> 'orientationDidChangeNotification' has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange'

this class written like

```
class OrientationHandler {

var lastKnownOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation!

init() {
    setLastOrientation(UIDevice.current.orientation, defaultOrientation: .portrait)
    UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    
    
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: orientationDidChange(_:))
 
    
    
    
}

func setLastOrientation(_ deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation, defaultOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation?) {
    
    // set last device orientation but only if it is recognized
    switch deviceOrientation {
    case .unknown, .faceUp, .faceDown:
        lastKnownOrientation = defaultOrientation ?? lastKnownOrientation
        break
    default:
        lastKnownOrientation = deviceOrientation
    }
}

func orientationDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    
    setLastOrientation(deviceOrientation, defaultOrientation: nil)
}

deinit {
    UIDevice.current.endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
  }
}
```

> how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

after searching , i solve it like this

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil, using: orientationDidChange(_:))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.screenOrientationChanged,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func deviceOrientationDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        print(orientation)
    }
```